# Initializing sorted collections from XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `SortedObservableCollection` class (initially based on [this](http://softcollections.codeplex.com/)). It does exactly what it promises - it is a generic collection, which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and maintains its elements in  sorted order (according to a provided `IComparer`). The order is only checked upon insertion though - when an item is being inserted, it is inserted into a correct place into the collection.

However I encountered a major issue while trying to initialize the collection from XAML with syntax like this (the `Items` property is of `SortedObservableCollection<MyItem>` type, `Priority` is the sorting key):

```
<my:SomeElement.Items>
    <my:MyItem Priority="0">
    <my:MyItem Priority="2">
    <my:MyItem Priority="1">
</my:SomeElement.Items>
```

This should result in collection with items in order 2, 1, 0, but it results in order 1, 2, 0.

It took me quite some time to discover the cause: **Collection items are first constructed, then added to the collection and only then are their properties' values assigned.**

I couldn't find this behavior documented anywhere and I agree it doesn't really matter usually. But in my case, the `Priority` property is always of value 0, so the sorting doesn't take occur at all (in fact, the items are inserted in reverse order than they are in XAML). And the, after the sorting has taken place, the `Priority` is initialized.

**Did you encounter this behavior yourself? Why is the XAML implemented like this? How can I work around this issue?**

The only solution I can think of is to let the items implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and then subscribe to it in the `Add` method (and then update the order when necessary), but I guess this would bring more trouble than it is worth (performance, memory leaks...).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming at a collection which is properly sorted at all times, then you'll need to go for the listening approach. You could make you items support a weak event mechanism to prevent them from holding a strong reference to the collection.

Another approach would be to defer sorting until the collection is "fully constructed". You could for example have a flag `isSorted` in your collection implementation. Have this flag set to `false` whenever the collection is modified (for simplicity) and check it before the collection is "read".

Something like this:

```
public void Add(T item)
{
  _innerList.Add(item);
  _isSorted = false;
}
```

and:

```
public int IndexOf(T item)
{
  EnsureSorted();
  return _innerList.IndexOf(item);
}
```

where `EnsureSorted` could look something like this:

```
private void EnsureSorted()
{
  if (!_isSorted)
  {
    _innerList.Sort(_comparer);
    _isSorted = true;

    // TODO: Raise the CollectionChanged event here, specifying
    //       NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset
  }
}
```

This should make your collection appear sorted while still allowing it to be unsorted while populating the list.

Perhaps this would be a feasible workaround?

---

**Update:**

I created a simple observable collection with this kind of deferred sorting. I think you might find it helpful, at least it should clearify what I mean.

The idea is to call the `EnsureSorted` method just before "reading" the collection and to clear the `isSorted` flag whenever collection is modified.

```
public class SortedObservableCollection<T> : IList<T>, IList, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly List<T> _innerList;
    private IComparer<T> _comparer;
    private bool _isSorted;

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public SortedObservableCollection()
        : this(null)
    {
    }

    public SortedObservableCollection(IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        _innerList = new List<T>();
        _comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
    }

    // Call this before "reading" collection
    private void EnsureSorted()
    {
        if (!_isSorted)
        {
            _innerList.Sort(_comparer);
            _isSorted = true;
        }
    }

    // Call this after modifying the collection
    private void NotifyChanged()
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        }

        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }

        _isSorted = false;
    }

    #region List implementation

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        EnsureSorted();
        return _innerList.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        EnsureSorted();
        _innerList.Insert(index, item);
        NotifyChanged();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        EnsureSorted();
        _innerList.RemoveAt(index);
        NotifyChanged();
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureSorted();
            return _innerList[index];
        }

        set
        {
            EnsureSorted();
            _innerList[index] = value;
            NotifyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _innerList.Add(item);
        NotifyChanged();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _innerList.Clear();
        NotifyChanged();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _innerList.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        EnsureSorted();
        _innerList.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _innerList.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        if (!_innerList.Remove(item))
        {
            return false;
        }

        NotifyChanged();
        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        EnsureSorted();
        return _innerList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    // Non-generic implementation omitted for brevity...
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. The collection is used primarily as data source for other controls, which means, it doesn't ask for its updates, it waits for them. Therefore I have no way of knowing when the collection is fully constructed.

Comment: I guess it should work anyway. Just make sure that you have your ObservableCollection implementation raising the appropriate events.

Comment: The easiest way is probably (depending on your implementation) to raise the Reset change action after the list was sorted. I updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: @Marten But what code does in this case call the EnsureSorted method? Perhaps I could call it after the  InitializeComponents method call, but that would be extremely ugly solution...

Comment: If you just follow the idea that you call EnsureSorted just before any read access to the collection you should be fine. Others control which bind to the collection will both add them selves as listeners to the CollectionChanged event and read items from the collection. When they read the first item, the collection would get sorted.